# creating a JavaScript sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create fix position element function where i am trying to force my footer to always stay at the bottom of the page. The CSS properties `position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;` will not work due to the way my html is structured. [click here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/GmNSn/)

fixed wont work, the red background will be an ajax call - the red block will not have a fixed height also it will be place onto of the div wrapper, if i use fixed position you will notice that the black element will overlap the red block. i basically need the black block to always sit underneath the red block

I know there is a Javascript function which detects where the element should be based on browser size. therefore the footer will stick to the bottom Based on my example can someone provide me with an example?

Comment: You messed up with usability if you're calling pop up which is higher than the screen.

Comment: @Yevgen not all i think you have misunderstood the question, the example i have provided in jsfiddle is just a quick prototype what i am working on. I not asking about usability i have put a request out for coding a javascript sticky footer

Comment: Re-write your explanation, I've spent almost all my time looking at this just trying to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GmNSn/8/)

You need to restructure your HTML a little bit. Stick a container `div` around everything and do the AJAX call in the section contained within in. You would then `position: relative` your footer in relation to the container and style the container with the red background.

EDIT: work on your question explanation if this isn't what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code, without using js, i just added position:fixed to footer and z-indizies to section and footer, so the footer is on "highest layer"

http://jsfiddle.net/GmNSn/5/

```
    section{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    z-index: 555;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 30px;
    z-index:0;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100px;
}

.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

footer{
    background: #000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: I want the black block to sit at the bottom of the red block not overlap it

Comment: hmn, then you can just use relative positioning, check this fiddle, you just have to make sure that the ajax-response is appended in front of the footer http://jsfiddle.net/GmNSn/7/

Comment: hmmm i think it's better if i more to the html, to demonstrate why that method won't work